# what is the meaning of " go to a jury with" here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

what is the meaning of " go to a jury with" here?

> Many sensible readers, we fear, will think we owe them an apology for
>   opening our columns to a controversy on such a subject as Spiritualism
>   and thus treating as an open or debatable question what should rather
>   be dismissed at once as either an imposture or a delusion. But even an
>   imposture may call for unmasking, and popular delusions howeverabsurd,
>   are often too important to be neglected by the wiser portion of
>   mankind . Is there, in reality, anything, as lawyers would say, to **go
>   to a jury with?** Well, on the one hand, we have abundance of alleged
>   experience which can hardly be called evidence, and a few depositions
>   of a more notable and impressive character. On the other hand, we have
>   many accounts of convicted impostors, and many authentic reports of
>   precisely such disappointments or discoveries as we should be led to
>   expect.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**jury**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/jury) makes decisions based on provable facts, not from rumour or gossip.

So the question

> Is there, in reality, anything, as lawyers would say, to go to a jury with?

means

> Is there enough evidence to convince anyone that [sceances, levitation etc] are genuine?